# Magisk/Xposed Module to have Android O like notifications (on Android N)?

Tags: android

I want to use apps like *Universal Copy* and *Tasker* but the permanent notifications clog up the notification shade too much. Is there a module that gives Android N the smaller permanent notifications like android O? I tried material design shade which did that but it got rid of alot of the Samsung notification draw things like NFC, blue-light filter, etc.